# How can i display a random text from an sqlite database in android studio to a new layout?

Tags: android, layout, android-sqlite

I want to display a text view previously shown in a ListView, after that it will be displayed in an other layout where it will be one which can be watch and another that will be compared to be sured it is correct.
My database is this

```
public class DataBaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Preguntas_y_Respuestas_Manager",
        TABLE_PyR = "PreguntasYRespuestas",
        KEY_ID = "id",
        KEY_PREGUNTA = "pregunta",
        KEY_RESPUESTA = "respuesta";

public DataBaseHandler(Context context) {

    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PyR + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_PREGUNTA + " TEXT," + KEY_RESPUESTA + " TEXT)");

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PyR);

    onCreate(db);

}

public void createPregunta_y_Respuesta(PreguntasYRespuestas pYr) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(KEY_PREGUNTA, pYr.getPregunta());
    values.put(KEY_RESPUESTA, pYr.getRespuesta());

    db.insert(TABLE_PyR, null, values);
    db.close();

}

public PreguntasYRespuestas getPyR(int id) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_PyR, new String[]{KEY_ID, KEY_PREGUNTA, KEY_RESPUESTA}, KEY_ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null, null);

    if(cursor!=null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    PreguntasYRespuestas preg_y_resp =  new PreguntasYRespuestas(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(2));
    db.close();
    return preg_y_resp;

}

public void deletePregunta(PreguntasYRespuestas pyr){

    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_PyR, KEY_ID + "=?",new String[]{String.valueOf(pyr.getId())});
    db.close();

}

public  int getPreguntasCount(){

    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_PyR, null);

    int count = cursor.getCount();
    db.close();
    cursor.close();

    return count;
}

public int UpdatePregunta(PreguntasYRespuestas pyr){

    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_PREGUNTA, pyr.getPregunta());
    values.put(KEY_RESPUESTA, pyr.getRespuesta());

    int rowsAffected = db.update(TABLE_PyR, values, KEY_ID + "=?", new String[] {String.valueOf(pyr.getId()) });
    db.close();

    return rowsAffected;

}

public List<PreguntasYRespuestas>getAllPreguntas(){

    List<PreguntasYRespuestas> pyr = new ArrayList<PreguntasYRespuestas>();

    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db. rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ TABLE_PyR, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){

        do {
            pyr.add(new PreguntasYRespuestas(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(2)));
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());

    }

    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return pyr;

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use an appropriate query to extract the potential texts to a Cursor.

Use `cursor.getCount()` to get the number of rows in the cursor.

Obtain a random number, as an integer, that is between 0 and the row count -1 (as cursor positioning is 0 based).

Then use `cursor.moveToPosition(yourrandomnumber);` and extract the data from the cursor (i.e.the text) from the row and finally use `cursor.close();`

Comment: Where do i use that code?, in my database or in another activity?

Comment: You could do have the code in either the DatabaseHandler or in the activity. However, following on with you putting DB related code in the DatabaseHandle you would likely code the above in a method within the DatabaseHandler class of e.g ` public String getRandomText() {.......}` and then call it from the respective activity, along the lines of `youredittext.setText(getRandomText(),TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);`